# Generate Same Salt everytime for Same String value

Tags: java, security, encryption, hash, salt

I need to add a salt to a hashed column. This hashed column is also used as an index in one of the tables. I don't want to use the same hard coded salt for all values for obvious reasons.

What can be the best way to generate a unique SAME salt value every time for the given String so when I hash the value i get the same output back (to help me search with the hashed value).

Update:
Thanks everyone for the inputs. 
More details - I have to encrypt a column in the database. This column is also used for searching the row in the table and after encrypting we can not use it for searching because there are chances that we can change the encryption keys at later point of time. Now to counter this we thought of adding a Hashed column in the table on which we can perform the search (since we are not going to change the Hashed algorithm we can always use this for searching purpose). To make this hashed column more secure we thought of adding a salt to it. And since Salt should be random we will not be able to generate same hash function every time for same value unless we use the same Salt for all rows. So this is why I was trying to figure out a way where I can generate same salt for same String every time.
But I think after going through all the comments and suggestions by you guys one thing I am sure is that this is not a good design and I should rethink on my approach :(

Comment: If you already have the value encrypted in the database, it should be easy to search for it. Just encrypt the input before searching, then search for the encrypted value in the database, the hash-value will be entirely unnecessary then. Even searching case insensitive is possible, add a second field with the encrypted lower-case input. Changing the key should be no problem neither, decrypt the values, encrypt them with the new key and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

Using the hash-value only as index or as foreign-key should be no problem (just include the salt in the hash-value), but i understand, that you want to refind the row, having only the original (unhashed) value.

This can never work, a column with properly salted hashes can never be used, to find the row. Often this means, that the design is flawed, a hashed value should not be something you have to search for. An example: to validate a password you should instead search for the username and then you can verify the password with the found password-hash.

If you are sure that you need to search for this hash-value, then your only options are to either use no salt (or same salt for all values), or to encrypt the value (two-way-encryption without IV). Of course, both of these options are weaker protections than properly hashing the value.

*Update:* According to your update, you already have the encrypted value in the database. This means, that you can search for it, without needing a hash-value. Just encrypt the sought-after value, before you do the query.

Comment: @Chris - When i wrote "either use no salt..." i meant no salt or the same salt for each value, because a constant salt is technically not a salt. And you are right that the IV encounters the same problems as the salt. What i actually meant is, if the value must be searchable, there is always a tradeoff in security. But if it is a requirement then it is a requirement.

Comment: @Chris - Oh that's not a problem, it is also my fault that i didn't write it more clear. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this would defeat the purpose of using a salt.  In order to serve its intended purpose, the salt should be as random as possible.

Think about it -- you could use a hash of the string as the "salt", then hash the original string and that "salt" together a second time.  But the resulting hash would still be a derivative of only the original string.  While this may provide just a small bit of security against a simple rainbow table, it just isn't enough.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Defense_against_rainbow_tables

Comment: I completely agree with you but the way existing system is set up I am not able to think of any other good approach. I need to hash the column which is also used for indexing. So I was trying to think of some approach where I can relate the generated salt to the actual string using some way.

Comment: Can you create a new relation table that has two columns, one with an ID and the other with the hash, then rework the other pieces of the application to use the new ID and determine the hash?  I've had to do something like that in the past when dealing with hashed SSNs.

Comment: i think i do not get it. how will i relate the ID and the actual value?

Comment: @Chris -- wow..  I just don't know how to react to this.  You should not derive salt from the original value.  What you're recommending is security through obscurity at best, and defeats the purpose of using salt.  If you need your hash to be deterministic -- don't use salt.

Comment: @Chris - The issue you're raising really becomes a question of security through obscurity vs. a properly designed solution.  Chances are good that if somebody has a hold of your database tables they also have some insight into your hashing process (source code or binaries that can be de-compiled).  At that point, any additional security you had via the "secret" salting technique is lost.  So I would consider a static/deterministic salt effectively the same as no salt at all.  Think of it sort of like the complexity of an algorithm n^2 + 3n = O(n^2)  -- the 3 is meaningless.

Comment: @Chris -- I do see where you're coming from.  I agree that in practice it does add another (albeit low) hurdle.  If you were a security professional, would you recommend your clients use a system-wide non random salt?  Or conversely -- if your system were to undergo a security review, how would you defend against the finding that the hashes were not securely generated and therefore undermine the effort to encrypt the adjacent column?

Comment: @Chris - Call it a hash, do not introduce the concept of salt, and call it a day.  You're unfairly passing judgement on an answer to a question that was edited after I'd answered it.  "What can be the best way to generate a unique SAME salt value every time for the given String".  This demonstrates a basic misunderstanding of the purpose of using salt, a misunderstanding that is quite prevalent.

Comment: @Chris - What we are really arguing over is silly -- the definition of "cryptographic salt".  I believe that a salt must be truly random, you apparently do not.  I encourage you to read http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/04/properly-salting-passwords-case-against.html  Your entitled attitude and the way you use this site honestly infuriates me, but I am going to take a deep breath and move on.

Comment: @Chris - No worries, there are many shades of grey.  The place you find yourself, where security requirements meet functional requirements often dictates the best tool for the job.  If your stored data are sensitive but you *need* to retain some way to look up your records by that data -- then the technique described is reasonable.  It is good you're making an effort to secure your data to the fullest extent possible.

Answer (score 0):

The salt can be stored in the same table as the salted+hashed value. When you insert a new record, generate a new random salt, salt+hash the value, and save both the hashed value and the salt in that record.

Comment: but this will not help in searching on salted+Hashed value.

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't. A good hash algorithm is relatively slow to compute, so it would not be a good candidate for a field to be searched. I think you may need to reevaluate your schema. If you posted the problem you're trying to solve in more detail, you may be able to get an alternative solution.

Answer (score -1):

Salt does not need to be particularly secure, so you could derive the salt from the string by using a non-crypto hash, perhaps [FNV hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/).  You can then use a cryptographic hash, like SHA-256, together with the salt to make the secure hashed value.  A non-crypto hash also has the advantage of being faster.

Comment: While a salt doesn't need to be secret, it musn't be derived from the original value. This would negate the purpose of the salt, because it becomes just a more complex hash function. It would then be possible to build 1 rainbow table, to get all the original values.

Comment: Then use a secure keyed hash, like HMAC.  A single secret master key can be used to HMAC as many strings as you could reasonably want.

Comment: @rossum: But that HMAC provides no protection against rainbow tables.

Comment: @Billy True, but it is not clear to me what level of security the questioner needs.  HMAC is not perfect, but it may be good enough for purpose.  To some extent we are in the dark on the precise requirements.

Comment: @Chris - If you use a constant salt, you have at least the advantage of a secret server-side key (pepper), because it is independend of the actual value. If you derrive it from the value itself, the algorithm (code) to get the salt is a secret as well, but if you would build a framework this way this secret would be public knowledge.